# How to add object to an array inside another array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

On reactJS. I created a Class `Client`. Inside this Class I have an array called `PurchaseList`. I try to add to this array an array of object called `purchase`. But for some reason I got `Uncaught TypeError: clientList[currentClientIdx].purchaseList.push is not a function`
(I have to specify that `clientList` is a state defined in the App.js component )

How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
//this is the Class:
class Client {
  purchaseList = [];
  constructor(id, username, password, moneyAmount) {
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.moneyAmount = moneyAmount;
  }
}
```

This is the code to add the data to `PurchaseList`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function Action({clientList,currentClientIdx}) {
    
    const [company,setCompany]=useState()
    const [amount,setAmount]=useState()
    const [purchase,setPurchase]=useState()
     
    
    const handlePurchase=()=>{
     
      setPurchase({company:company,amount:amount})
      console.log(purchase);  
      clientList[currentClientIdx].purchaseList.push(purchase)
      console.log(clientList[currentClientIdx]); 
    }

return (
    <div>
        
        <input type="text" placeholder='Company'  onChange={(e)=>setCompany(e.target.value)}/>
        <input type="number" placeholder='Amount' onChange={(e)=>setAmount(e.target.value)} />
        
        <button onClick={()=>handlePurchase()}>Purchase</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `purchaseList` is an array.

You have to initialize `purchaseList` as an empty array before you can call `push` on it. Also, you should check if it already is an array, just so you aren't overwriting values:

```js
if (Array.isArray(clientList[currentClientIdx].purchaseList)) {
  // Array already exists, push to end of array
  clientList[currentClientIdx].purchaseList.push(purchase);
} else {
  // Array does not exist, create array and push element
  clientList[currentClientIdx].purchaseList = [];
  clientList[currentClientIdx].purchaseList.push(purchase);
}
```